# send websocket message to two clients

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I started a personal project from gorilla chat example. Every time a client calls "register" I check if it has an opponent. Suppose clients are game players. What I am trying to do is to couple clients two per two.

Clients are:

```
type Client struct {
    hub      *Hub
    opponent *Client
    conn     *websocket.Conn
    send     chan []byte
}
```

So when I client call register, if exists one client with opponent nil, I tie two clients with

```
c.opponent = client
client.opponent = c
```

And then, I send together a message:

```
c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, dat)
client.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, dat)
```

but no one receive the message. How can I send a message to just two clients?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "log"
)

func newHub() *Hub {
    return &Hub{
        broadcast:  make(chan []byte),
        register:   make(chan *Client),
        unregister: make(chan *Client),
        clients:    make(map[*Client]bool),
    }
}

func (h *Hub) run() {
    for {
        select {

        // register new client
        case client := <-h.register:
            log.Println("register")
            h.clients[client] = true
            for c := range h.clients {
                if c != client {
                    if c.opponent == nil {
                        c.opponent = client
                        client.opponent = c
                        dat := []byte(`{"foo":"bar"}`)
                        c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, dat)
                        client.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, dat)
                    }
                }
            }

        case client := <-h.unregister:
            log.Println("unregister")
            if _, ok := h.clients[client]; ok {
                delete(h.clients, client)
                close(client.send)
            }

        case message := <-h.broadcast:
            for client := range h.clients {
                select {
                case client.send <- message:
                default:
                    close(client.send)
                    delete(h.clients, client)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Send messages to channel `client.send` instead of writing directly to connection to avoid data race on webscoket write.  Confirm that pairing code is executing using debugger or by sprinkling in some logging code.

Comment: `c.send <- dat` and `client.send <- dat`?

Comment: Yes, that will fix the data race.  Although the data race is something that you should fix, that's probably not the issue here.  Add some log statements to confirm that pairing is happening.